# Are there any wikis that use BlueSpice?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, bluespice

My problem is that I cannot find any BlueSpice wikis to check out how they look like so I can make my mind up about implementing this software in my MediaWiki too

I keep trying to find examples of BlueSpice wikis without any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a reference site but this may help.

1. [BlueSpice MediaWiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueSpice_MediaWiki) is seemingly well established.
2. [MidiaWiki provides a BlueSpice profile](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/BlueSpice).
3. The [BlueSpice.com site](https://bluespice.com/) site also includes some things that may help you:

   - The '**Our customers**' section and its [View all references](https://bluespice.com/references/) link identifies existing implementations. You might reach out to them.
4. The [SourceForge: BlueSpice free Discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/bluespice/discussion/1249667/) has resources and forums with which you might be able to answer your questions, or contact existing users.